# IIS multiple domain session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

We have a website which is currently on a .nl domain. We want to have the same site on a .be domain and the binding for that works perfect. But when someone is surfing to the .be site we want to change the logo to our .be logo.

This is done by using code like:

```
if (request.Url.Authority == "domain.be")
{
    //change logo
}
```

Still so far, so good.

The site also has a shop part. This part is protected by SSL but only on our .nl site. So we have a `web.config` redirect for all `.be/winkelwagen/` (winkelwagen is shoppingcart in dutch) to our .nl domain. But now here is the problem. If we redirect to the .nl domain, our check for the logo change isn't working anymore while we still wish to acknowledge that the customer is a .be customer by placing the .be logo.

We tried to put this information in a cookie, but since the domain is changed, the cookie is lost.

Sessions also don't work well because the sessionid is saved in a cookie.

Any ideas how I can implement a solution for this problem?

---

UPDATE

The web.config redirect is as follows (and works correctly)

```
 <rule name="Redirect NL winkelwagen" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.nl$" negate="true" />
           <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/winkelwagen/" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.nl/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      <match url="(.*)" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: Are you transferring any other information about the customer? I wonder if the parent site should be a customer facet - of course, that assumes that they're logged in, and of course login should happen only inside SSL, so chicken:egg. I wonder if a better approach might just be to have 2 SSL endpoints (whether that means in IIS, or inside a front-end terminator such as haproxy)

Comment: Can you copy-paste the section of the web.config where you put the "redirect" ?

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino copy-pasted it. But the redirect is not the problem. That is working. The problem is the cross domain cookie/session

Comment: @MarcGravell No, because the login is inside the winkelwagen (shoppingcart) area.

Comment: @MarcGravell But we do wish to keep the user logged in once the user goes back to a non-NL non-Winkelwagen page (for example `domain.be/contact/`).

Comment: I think you are in a dead end street. You cannot share cookie (as you know). Did you consider to use only a .com and arrange language and logo based on user choice?

Comment: Pure_speculation_mode=ON   Or, more more complex, consider more intelligent redirection from .be to .nl passing also information about "sessionid". From my point of view this requires a persistent session storage (sql, mongodb, other) and, important, poses some security issues. Consider them very carefully. [Update: with sessionid I do not mean the asp.net sessionid, but a yours "sessionid", created and managed by you... very very risky]